# QBASIC Decimal to Binary conversion

Tags: qbasic

I have converted a decimal number to binary using STR$() in QBASIC. But I need a way to convert decimal number to binary without using string functions. Thanks.

My Code :

```
CLS
INPUT N
WHILE N <> 0
    E = N MOD 2
    B$ = STR$(E)
    N = FIX(N / 2)
    C$ = B$ + C$
WEND
PRINT "Output "; C$
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sample converts a numeric value to a binary string in Basic.

```
PRINT "Enter value";
INPUT Temp#
Out3$ = ""
IF Temp# >= False THEN
    Digits = False
    DO
        IF 2 ^ (Digits + 1) > Temp# THEN
            EXIT DO
        END IF
        Digits = Digits + 1
    LOOP
    FOR Power = Digits TO 0 STEP -1
        IF Temp# - 2 ^ Power >= False THEN
            Temp# = Temp# - 2 ^ Power
            Out3$ = Out3$ + "1"
        ELSE
            Out3$ = Out3$ + "0"
        END IF
    NEXT
END IF
PRINT Out3$
END
```

Comment: To print the binary value change Out3$ = Out3$ + "1" to Print "1";

Answer (score 1):

When you want to display an integer value as binary, it seems logical to me to store it in a string variable, because it's only for display. So I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here.
Maybe you were looking for `LTRIM$` so you would get outputs like `11010` instead of `1 1 0 1 0` ?

You *could* store it in an integer value like in the code below. But, although the integer value will **look the same** as the string variable, it will in fact be a **completely different** value.

```
CLS
INPUT "Type a decimal number:", N
S$ = ""
I = 0
P = 1
WHILE (N <> 0)
  ' get right most bit and shift right
  E = N AND 1
  N = INT(N / 2) ' bit shift right
  ' format for dsplay
  S$ = LTRIM$(STR$(E)) + S$
  I = I + (E * P)
  P = P * 10
WEND
PRINT "Binary as string="; S$
PRINT "Binary as int="; I
END
```